# Debounce vue3 + nuxt3 js

Tags: vuejs3, debouncing, nuxt3

I have some question. I want debounce an emit event from child component to parent component ( using el-input in element plus).

I try learn some solutions but emit debounce not working such as watch input, emit modelValue. I want to pass 1 "debounce" parameter as above and prevent the code from working fine.

```js
//Custom Input
<script lang="ts" setup>
const search = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <CustomInput
    :model-value="search"
    placeholder="Search"
    type="search"
    class="w-full md:max-w-[330px]"
    :debounce="500"
    @update:modelValue="(newValue: string) => (search = newValue)"
  />
</template>
```

```js
//input
<script lang="ts" setup>
interface Props {
  modelValue?: string
  placeholder?: string
  type: string
  debounce: number
}
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  modelValue: '',
  placeholder: 'Please input',
  type: 'text',
  debounce: 0
})
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
// const debounceInput = debounce(() => {
//   let value = 'ok'
//   emit('update:modelValue', value)
// }, props.debounce)
const debounceInput = (e: any) => {
  let value = e.target.value
  emit('update:modelValue', value)
}
</script>

<template>
  <el-input
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :value="modelValue"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :type="type"
    class="base-input"
    :class="{
      search: type === 'search'
    }"
    @input="debounceInput"
  >
    <template #suffix>
      <el-icon>
        <img
          v-if="type === 'search'"
          class="w-[18px] h-[18px] mx-auto cursor-pointer"
          src="images/search.svg"
          alt="logo"
        />
      </el-icon>
    </template>
  </el-input>
</template>
```

```js
//debounce function
export const debounce = (callback: Function, delayTime: number) => {
  let timeOut
  return () => {
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => callback(), delayTime)
  }
}
```

Comment: [Paste code in your question, not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).  Also, what debugging steps have you done?  What does "not working" mean?  Any errors or notable behavior?  List some of the solutions you've tried. It'll help others not given redundant advice

Comment: I just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debouncing a function:

```js
export function debounce(func, timeout) {
  let timeoutId;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      func(...args);
    }, timeout);
  };
}
```

Then to use it:

```js
<script>
import { debounce } from 'debounce.js'

const debouncedInput = debounce((e) => 
  emit("update:modelValue", e.target.value),
  300 // timeout in ms
);
</script>
```

with a generic `<input>` for simplicity sake:

```html
<template>
  <input
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="debouncedInput"
    placeholder="Please input"
    type="text"
  />
</template>
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-kapitsa-yp7lg9?file=/src/components/CustomInput.vue) example.  Should also work just fine when implemented with `<el-input>` and typescript which I'll leave to you.

By the way, these properties you have on `<CustomInput>`:

```js
:modelValue="search"
@update:modelValue="(newValue: string) => (search = newValue)"
```

Can all be replaced with the following short-hand:

```js
v-model="search"
```

Comment: I tried your code and it is quite similar to my code. It really doesn't work with TypeScript and el-Input. I'm pretty sure about that

Comment: `@input` is the same for `<input>` as `<el-input>` and typescript is just... types.  it will work assuming correct implementation.  if you have a specific problem with the provided debounce function please update your question with your own updated code and what the implementation error is.

Comment: looking at the [el-input](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/input.html#attributes) documentation, there is no `:value` prop.  just use `v-model` instead

Comment: [here you go](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-5xajqu?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fdebounce.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2FCustomInput.vue)... working with element-plus and typescript

Comment: [plugin:vite:vue] v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable.
Use a v-bind binding combined with a v-on listener that emits update:x event instead.

Comment: It happens when I use "v-model" in your CustomInput. I know your code is correct but I don't understand why it's not running in my project

Comment: I just try :v-model in CustomInput ... but still not working :(

Comment: can you give me an explanation why it runs on STACK but not in IDE